# Childs not loaded in multiple transactions with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

That's basically my code:

```
// Start first transaction to create a school

// Here I set a student for the school
school.setStudent(new Student(id));

// I Save

// Then I Start a SECOND transaction to retrieve the same school

// I can read the childs without prolem. 
school.getStudent().getLanguage().getId();
```

Now, for some reasons, I want all the above in the same transaction. That's what happens:

```
// Start the transaction to create a school

// Here I set a student that exist in the DB for that new school
school.setStudent(new Student(id));

// I Save

// In the same transaction I retrieve a list of schools, and one of the schools is the newly created.

// In the newly created school I can't access the childs: null pointer exception on language
school.getStudent().getLanguage().getId(); //ERRROR
```

What happens in the fist case is that even if I set only the id for student, once persisted all the other information of the student are already in the DB, because the student is not new. I just want to create an association with the school.

But in the second case I haven't still terminated the transaction and for some reasons when I query the schhol again, the student contains only the id and not all the other information. Language indeed is null and generate exception.

I tried to add a session.flush() but doesn't fix the issue.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: are you using the same code to load the school from DB? can you share that block of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to set the school student to a new student having the ID of an existing one. You want to set the school student to the existing student. So just get it from the database instead of recreating it:

```
Student theExistingStudent = (Student) session.load(Student.class, id);
school.setStudent(theExistingStudent);
```

The above won't even make a query to get it from the database. It will asume the student exist and return a lazy-initialized proxy to the existing student. Of course, if you want to make sure the student indeed exists, you can also use

```
Student theExistingStudent = (Student) session.get(Student.class, id);
school.setStudent(theExistingStudent);
```